# Looking for a layout like FlowLayout but allows you to choose separate alignments for each component

Tags: java, layout

I have been looking for a layout much like FlowLayout but that allows you to set specific alignments for individual objects, instead of objects all being in one alignment.

I've already attempted to to use BorderLayout, but since I can't fit multiple objects into the same area I end up losing one of the two buttons I want to be on the edge of the screen.

This is the code I have working now:

```
closeBtn = new JLabel(" X ");
closeBtn = setUpBtn(closeBtn);
minBtn = new JLabel(" - ");
minBtn = setUpBtn(minBtn);
topText = new JLabel("Text");
topText = setUpBtn(topText);

setBackground(Color.black);
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
panel.add(topText);
panel.add(minBtn);
panel.add(closeBtn);
```

and the setUpBtn method:

```
JLabel setUpBtn(JLabel label) {
    label.setFont(Program.font);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    return label;
}
```

which yields this:

[image: result]

Instead of having it all aligned to the right side, I want the "Text" portion to be aligned to the left.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `GridBagLayout`? I think you can do this with that layout manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a GridBagLayout, as @PrasadKarunagoda suggested, and I played around with the weightx values until I got something that I liked.
Here is my final code:

```
closeBtn = new JLabel(" X");
closeBtn = setUpBtn(closeBtn);
minBtn = new JLabel(" - ");
minBtn = setUpBtn(minBtn);
topText = new JLabel("test");
topText = setUpBtn(topText);
centText = setUpBtn(new JLabel("0%"));
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints con = new GridBagConstraints();

setBackground(Color.black);

con.weightx = 0.7;
con.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
con.gridx = 0;
con.gridy = 0;
add(topText, con);

con.weightx = 1;
con.gridx = 1;
add(centText, con);

con.weightx = 0;
con.gridx = 2;
add(minBtn, con);

con.gridx = 3;
add(closeBtn, con);
```